# How to get my scanner work on ubuntu

Tags: hp, scanner

I am a `HP deskjet f380` All in one printer that has a in built scanner too.

The printer is working fine. But the scanner is not. Whenever I give a scan, it says `I/O error, cannot interact with device`.

I even tried installing the official drivers from HP website but no luck. Can any one please help?

Comment: Please show us the output of `sane-find-scanner` and `scanimage -L`

Comment: also read this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HpAllInOne :)

Comment: I don't get any output.